# How to make sure that onclick event in jQuery applies to the newly updated elements of the class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have a set of links with a class `app-context-link` on my page – just some `<a>` menu elements.

They are generated when the page is loaded from some data that the page receives from a JSON.

I then apply the following on click jQuery function, to make sure that when a user clicks on one of those elements, a certain procedure is performed:

```
    $(".app-context-link").on('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
          // do something
    }
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on one of the items, I want to highlight the item they clicked, perform some action on the JSON, and then return a new menu to the user that has other elements of the same class `app-context-link` – in this case the "old" onclick function does not apply to the newly added items, right? And then I can't get them to behave in the same way because of that.

Does anyone have an idea how I could resolve it?

I know I probably have to rewrite everything very carefully with callbacks, etc. but maybe there's an easier solution already inside jQuery and I'm just missing something?

And as a bonus track – if I decided to leave the menu as it is and just to highlight the element clicked (through appending a class), how would I do that? Sorry if that last question sounds stupid, but I'm a novice and feel a bit confused...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delegate event, e.g:

```
$(document).on('click', ".app-context-link", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
          // do something
    });
```

Now selector will be filtered on each click.

`document` is an example, usually, you'd prefer to bind it to closest static container

Answer (score 1):

```
function bindLink() {
    $(".app-context-link").click(function() {
          // do something
    });
}
```

Now, everytime you change your data, you can call your bind function (bindLink()).

Comment: This will bind multiple events to existing elements on the page. To prevent this, you'd need to bind using `.on()` so that before you re-bind you can call `.off()` first to remove the previous event handlers before adding new ones.